# Keep storage full would unable to read HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

Recently 500 GB HDD is died I assume it cause storage was full.

So keeping storage full would be cause of unable to read the HDD?

Also how much free space should be on HDD to make things work (OS operation), etc?

Comment: “So keeping storage full would be cause of unable to read the HDD?” - this isn’t likely

Comment: A healthy HDD as a device is always full. I mean you can read all of it and get exactly as many bytes as its size in bytes; for any HDD this is a fixed number. A filesystem can be full. Full filesystem on a HDD does not make the HDD fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect.

At HDD's level there's no concept of "full". Storage devices are pretty dumb, they're just ordered byte containers. Each byte consists of 8 bits, each of those can be either 0 or 1.

To make this bunch of bytes usable you have to create a filesystem on it. A filesystem is a drive's table of contents. If some disk area is not specified to be used for anything in the table of contents, it's unused. *Some* data is still there, because bytes always hold some data, but it's not used for anything. It could be factory-zeroed not-yet-used space, random gibberish or remains of deleted files. Whatever it is, it's ready to be reused for something else when space is needed, and for HDD it's just data like any other. SSDs, memory cards etc. work like this too.

One exception is MMC memory cards, which became unreadable once they were full for a reason I don't know. They've been superseded by SD cards by now.

You've experienced a hardware failure. We don't know any details, so we can't tell what was the cause, but it could've even been just a random failure. It happens all the time. That's why you should have backups.

It's recommended to keep at least 10-20% of filesystem free for other reasons: stuffing a filesystem full increases fragmentation. On SSDs it also reduces efficiency of wear leveling, possibly shortening disk's lifespan.